# MobileApp: Documents Directory

Tags: android, ios

Do Apple and Android create a unique `Documents` directory for each app? And is the documents directory easily accessible by the average user?

Comment: There are two on Android. getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir(). The last is accessable for every user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for iOS, the OS creates a documents directory. It's not directly accessible by the user, but applications can be implemented to follow a document model that lets the user load and save documents inside the app.

I'll let an Android dev answer for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of how easy it is to grab a file URL with name `fileName` in the documents directory for iOS. Written for Swift 3.

```
    var documentURL= try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    documentURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```